# pyqtgraph: calling PlotDataItem.setData gives TypeError: PySide.QtCore.QPointF.__add__ called with wrong argument types

Tags: python, pyside, pyqtgraph

**Background**

- I am using `pyqtgraph` to make an interactive program that plots and analyzes some data.
- Versions of relevant things:

  - PySide version 1.2.1

    ```
    from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
    ```
  - `pyqtgraph` version 0.9.10 (latest at the moment):

    ```
    from <my own package>.external import pyqtgraph
    ```
  - On Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
  - Python 2.7.6

**Code Structure**

- `self.w.dotPlot` is a `pyqtgraph.PlotWidget` object
- I draw a box by doing this:

  ```
  self.timeBox = self.w.dotPlot.plot(x=self.baseTimeBoxX,y=self.baseTimeBoxY,...)
  ```

  where:

  ```
          from numpy import r_
          self.baseTimeBoxX = r_[0.0,0.0,100.0,100.0,0.0]
          self.baseTimeBoxY = r_[-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0]
  ```
- `self.w.timeBox` is thus an instance of  `pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.PlotDataItem.PlotDataItem`
- When the user clicks on the plot, I want to move the box in the X direction only.  To do this, I figure out the `clickedXCoord`, add this to self.baseTimeBoxX, and now want to update `self.w.timeBox` to use these x coordinates.  To do so, I call

  ```
  self.w.timeBox.setData(
      x=(clickedXCoord+self.baseTimeBoxX),
      y=self.baseTimeBoxY
  )
  ```

**The Problem**

Here is the traceback that I get:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "doesntMatter.py", line <whatever>, in _moveTimeBox
    self.w.timeBox.setData(x=(clickedXCoord+self.baseTimeBoxX),y=self.baseTimeBoxY)
TypeError: 'PySide.QtCore.QPointF.__add__' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide.QtCore.QPointF.__add__(numpy.ndarray)
Supported signatures:
  PySide.QtCore.QPointF.__add__(PySide.QtCore.QPointF)
```

**Things I have tried**:

- Instead of changing the data in the existing `PlotDataItem` using `self.w.timeBox.setData`, I tried just creating a whole new one:

  ```
  self.w.timeBox = self.w.dotPlot.plot(
  x=(clickedXCoord+self.baseTimeBoxX),
  y=self.baseTimeBoxY
  )
  ```

  I got basically the same error

Comment: The traceback seems pretty clear: you can only add a [`QPointF`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpointf.html) to another `QPointF`.

Comment: @ekhumoro The traceback is clearer than some I've seen, but I'm not trying to add anything to a QPointF.  According to the documentation [here](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/plotdataitem.html), the setData method takes the same arguments as the `__init__` method, and the call I have made is perfectly valid.  I am not directly calling QPointF.__add__, nor can I see in the debugger where this call occurred.

Comment: There is only one use of `+` in that traceback: `clickedXCoord+self.baseTimeBoxX`. And the error occurs in `doesntMatter.py`, not wherever `setData` is defined.

Comment: silly me, I was adding a QPointF rather than just a scalar to `self.baseTimeBoxX`.  Thanks, ekhumoro.